# Azure Boards: how restrict change work item state

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I want what change work item state was strict like my work flow (not allow move work items to any state) or shall do warning about incorrect state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature on preview only. You can find documentation here: [Restrict state transitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops#restrict-state-transitions). If you want to test it you [should request this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-171-update#state-transition-restriction-rules-private-preview).

> If you are interested in participating in the private preview, please
> email us directly with your organization name.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a limit of 10 restrictions per rule, that is rather odd to me.